# How to put an image variable as a background using tailwind in React?

Tags: reactjs

Hey i am learning React and i am creating a React application where in one of my components i am importing one of my images from my imagefolder.

```js
import Image from '../images/image.jpg';
```

I would like to use this image as a background by using a tailwind className

```js
export const Gallery = () => {

    return (
        <div className="bg-[url('{Image}')]"></div>
    )
}
```

i tried it this way but the image isnt rendering and i get nothing back.

Did i do something wrong here?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't use tailwind, but wouldn't `"bg-[url('{Image}')]"` just be a string? That's not a template string, so how is the variable actually being inserted there?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing the image, simply reference the image path:

```
<div className="bg-[url('../images/image.jpg')]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Imho, The best way to do this will be to extend theme in tailwind config.

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'hero-pattern': "url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')",
        'footer-texture': "url('/img/footer-texture.png')",
      }
    }
  }
```

tailwind [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#customizing-your-theme)